# Why can't I access/use $this->option('debug') in a artisan command class' __construct method?

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

I am trying to create a artisan command with a --debug [option](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan#options) in laravel. To use the debug switch within the whole class scope I use the __construct and assign it to a class property.

```php
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->debug = $this->option('debug');
    }
```

there is no problem when I use $this->option('debug') within the handle method. But when I use it in the __construct then I get

> Call to a member function getOption() on null {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError(code: 0):
>   Call to a member function getOption() on null at
>   /Users/user/Sites/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:310)

I am not sure but it looks like as if the option() is not ready at construct time. Checked the document but could't find anything. Is there any one who knows something about it or a way how I could accomplish that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like you can't access any of the [InputInterface's methods](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Input/InputInterface.php) because [they're just not initialised](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php#L170) at this point.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$this->option('debug')` in the `handle()` not in the `__construct()`